# Form data not being sent to MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

Have a simple registration form that is being linked to a php file in order to send the info to a database but everytime i try it the data isnt showing up in the phpMyAdmin database??

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$details = $_POST['details'];

$user="root";
$password="secure";
$database="darrenweircharity";
mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO registrationdetails(name, address, number, email, details)".
"VALUES('$name', '$address', '$number', '$email', '$details' NOW())";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Please *don't* use values from `$_POST` directly in your query.

Comment: Use PDO, reorganize your code, and replace with VALUES('".$name."', '".$address."', '".$number."', '".$email."', '".$details."')

Comment: Why do you have a `NOW()` there?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Did you try to do "mysql_query() or die(mysql_error)"?.
Other than that, you have no space between the table name and the list of columns (which has no column listed for the "NOW()" value), and a missing comma between "$details" and "NOW()".

Answer (score 1):

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Try with:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO registrationdetails(name, address, number, email, details)".
         "VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $address . "', '" . $number . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $details . "');";
```

You have `NOW()` at the end of the query that shouldn't be there.

Also note that your code has an SQL injection vulnerability (see [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)), I suggest you to prepare queries via `PDO`.

Comment: Get it right first time :P I've seen you edit your post a good three times so far;

Comment: @DarylGill what's the matter? I improve my answer!

Answer (score 0):

protect from possible SQL injection:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($number);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$details = mysql_real_escape_string($details);
```

replace with:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO registrationdetails (`name`, `address`, `number`, `email`, `details`)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$number', '$email', '$details')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO registrationdetails (name, address, number, email, details, date_time)
    VALUES ('{$name}', '{$address}', '{$number}', '{$email}', '{$details}', NOW())
";
```

Replace the `date_time` with your column_name. And remember to escape all submitted values with `mysql_real_escape_string` before inserting them into the database.